# PHP internals - getting a boolean argument

Tags: php, php-internals

While writing and looking at some PHP extension's source code I noticed that some use a LONG type flag to parse a boolean parameter:

```
bool new_map_embed;

if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &new_map_embed) == FAILURE) {
    RETURN_FALSE;
}
```

Why is that? Why not using the `b` flag instead?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the programmer made a mistake (perhaps they didn't know `b` existed?), or the parameter is not actually a boolean (accepts other values, perhaps). This isn't common practice.

In PHP 5, `IS_BOOL` stored its value in the same place as `IS_LONG` anyway, so you might have been forgiven for thinking you should use `l` here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like:

```
zend_bool new_map_embed;

if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "b", &new_map_embed) == FAILURE) {
    RETURN_FALSE;
}
```

Please look into real example inside the file zend_builtin_functions.c, and then search for zend_bool, you will see how [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) uses it.

Comment: I know I can use `b` my question is why parsing as long `l` is a common practice

Comment: @ShlomiHassid Why do you think it is common practice? It isn't.

Comment: @Nikic I'm seeing it more and more just wondering why and is this a good practice

Comment: zend_bool is unsigned char (zend_types.h: typedef unsigned char zend_bool;) and when you use long, you are inadvertently passing the address of 4 consecutive chars. and inside the api this is being treated as consecutive char without any loss of generality. You can verify by changing the value of new_map_embed=0xffffff0 (assuming long=4 bytes) and you will find that only value of lsb changes and rest of value remain uneffected after the call to zend_parse_parameters. And also if php core is not using it, so I assume its not right practice.